# Sorting issue with limit and offset MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I am facing sorting issue in mysql

See the output of below query:

```
select astrologers.id,astrologers.name,chat_online,online,experience from `astrologers` 
where `astrologers`.`status` = '1' 
order by experience asc limit 10;
```

| id | name | chat_online | online | experience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Astro Anoop | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 20 | Test Astro2 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | Test anoop | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 4 | Anoop Kumar trivedi | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 7 | Test | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 58 | Neeraj yadav | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 45 | Satish Kumar Gupta | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 56 | AP Sharma | 1 | 0 | 15 |
| 40 | VG Astrologer App | 1 | 0 | 55 |

In above result id 58 (Neeraj yadav) is at 6th position but when I run the same query with `limit 3`, same id 58 (Neeraj yadav) is at 3rd position:

```
select astrologers.id,astrologers.name,chat_online,online,experience 
from `astrologers` 
where `astrologers`.`status` = '1' 
order by experience asc limit 3;
```

| id | name | chat_online | online | experience |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | Test Astro2 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 15 | Astro Anoop | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 58 | Neeraj yadav | 1 | 0 | 5 |

The 3rd row in above result should be id 3 (Test anoop) but it gives id 58 (Neeraj yadav)

Is this bug in mysql?

Comment: Why should it be `3` and not `58`? They both have the exact same `experience` so any one of the three is correct. Is there another column that you are wanting to sort by in addition to `experience`? Perhaps you want `ORDER BY experience, id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a bug in MySQL?

No. The problem is that your sort is not deterministic, and gives ties in the third position:

```
|  3 | Test anoop          |           0 |      0 |          5 |
|  4 | Anoop Kumar trivedi |           0 |      0 |          5 |
|  7 | Test                |           0 |      0 |          5 |
| 58 | Neeraj yadav        |           1 |      0 |          5 |
```

All 4 users have the same experience, hence leaving the database to figure out how they should be sorted.

When asked to return to top 3 rows, the database picks the first two, and then one of the 4 ties. The result that you get might not be consistent over consequent executions of the same query, as you are starting to see.

Bottom line: know you data; if you want a deterministic result, then use a deterministic sort. We could, for example, use `id` to break the ties, hence making the result predictable:

```
order by experience, id limit 3
```

Comment: MySQL first fetches the result and then applies the limit na ?, in this case, it result should be the same irrespective of the limit and offset

Comment: work with this but I don't understand the logic. Mysql always gives priority to the first created row if the sort is tied. @gmb

Comment: @SatishGupta: *Mysql always gives priority to the first created row if the sort is tied.*: that's a common misunderstanding. Your experience might trick you into thinking that the database follows a certain rule, but the database actually does not guarantee anything in that case. This is not a documented behavior, and it may or may not work as you expect without qualifying as a bug.